# Using SpringSession with Google Cloud Datastore for Session Clustering

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, spring-session

I have been doing research to try find a way to use SpringSession to Session Cluster our cloud applications using Google Cloud Datastore. I have been having some trouble finding a sample implementation of this.

I noticed that the SpringSession samples only provide samples for redis, hazelcast and jdbc. I am wondering if someone could help point me in the right direction for setting up Session Clustering with GCP using SpringSession?

Comment: You may be able to get some inspiration from the experimental [implementation for Tomcat](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tomcat-runtime/tree/master/tomcat-gcp-lib/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/runtimes/tomcat/session). Similarly, in Jetty there is a module that implements [something similar](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-gcloud/jetty-gcloud-session-manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Session itself does not provide Google Cloud Datastore backed implementation of `SessionRepository`. To my knowledge there's no 3rd party extensions providing Google Cloud Datastore backed implementation either.

However, implementing `SessionRepository` (or `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`) backed by your desired data store should be a fairly straightforward task, and reusing existing Spring Session infrastructure should be very easy. Here's the snippet of such configuration:

```
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class SpringHttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public MySessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        // instantiate and configure MySessionRepository
    }

}
```

When implementing `SessionRepository`, take a look at [section of Spring Session's reference manual dedicated to that topic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#custom-sessionrepository).